# Angular Dependency Injection Annotation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I've been reading angular js dependency injection reference here

[Angular DI](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

There they claim that the recommended way of injecting dependencies is

```
myModule.controller('myController',['$scope','dep1',
                                    function($scope1,dep1){
            //Controller code
}]);
```

Rather than implicit injection

```
myModule.controller('myController',function($scope,dep1){
            //Controller code
});
```

And they even mention the second way is less tightly coupled but insist on using the first type of injection

Is there any valid technical reason for this?

Comment: Check: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md